# Zend Framework routes.ini with multiple routes but the same module/controller/action destination?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, zend-route

i've got a problem with the following routes.ini configuration file of my Zend Framework PHP Application. I would like to use just own created static urls. I dont't want use some kinds of :language/ route! (SEO requirement). How can i do that kind of routing?

```
[routes]

;default
routes.businessregistration_fieldautovalidation.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.businessregistration_fieldautovalidation.route = "/business/registration/fieldautovalidation"
routes.businessregistration_fieldautovalidation.defaults.module = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_fieldautovalidation.defaults.controller = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_fieldautovalidation.defaults.action = "fieldautovalidation"

;de

routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_de.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_de.route = "/unternehmen/registrierung"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_de.defaults.module = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_de.defaults.controller = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_de.defaults.action = "index"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.defaults.locale = "de_DE"

;en

routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.route = "/business/registration"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.defaults.module = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.defaults.controller = "businessregistration"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.defaults.action = "index"
routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_en.defaults.locale = "en_US"
```

The problem is that just the first route ("de") get initialized by the zend router engine. Zend Router ignore the following english route. Is there any restriction that i only can use one route for one destination? Why?

Thanks a lot,

Stephan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. Sorry!

Problem: routes.businessregistration_businessregistration_**en**.defaults.locale = "de_DE"